# Why do certain HTTP headers need to be explicitly allowed in express?

Tags: express

When creating a basic express application, as I've seen in many articles, you must explicitly allow certain HTTP headers such as Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization etc. via res.header(...). There are many other request headers in a general HTTP request so why do these ones need to be granted permission? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> There are many other request headers in a general HTTP request so why do these ones need to be granted permission?

Some http headers are fundamental to basic http operations.  For example, `Origin` is used in the implementation of CORS (cross origin restrictions) which implements some safety features in a browser.

`Content-Type` is used to indicate to the recipient what type of content is being sent.

`Accept` is used to indicate what type of content the requester is willing to accept.

And so on...  Without these base level headers, fundamental parts of how HTTP works (particularly with a browser) will fundamentally break down.

By default, a basic Express application just uses the headers it thinks it needs to use.  So, unless you're wrapping some other security mechanism around it (like a proxy or firewall) that blocks all headers, you don't have to explicitly enable certain headers as Express will just use the headers that it needs.

---

Though nothing in your question mentions `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, your comment indicates maybe that's what you meant to be asking about.  `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is used for the process of deciding whether cross origin requests are allowed or not.  This is a browser security feature that helps control whether Javascript in a web page is allowed to access domains other than the one that the web page itself came from (these are called cross origin requests - requests to a different target than the origin of the web page itself).

If you don't want to enable cross origin requests, then you don't have to do anything with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.  If you do want to enable certain cross origin requests, then you will have to configure `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` appropriately and you may also need to handle an OPTIONS http request too (depending upon what type of cross origin request you are trying to enable).  The rules for cross origin requests from a browser are all spelled out in various specs and web-sites, but they are often confusing at first to fully understand.  Keep in mind that the CORS feature set to limit or enable cross origin requests is a browser-only capability as the actual limiting of things is implemented in the browser.  CORS does not limit any non-browser client (such as an http request made by a script or program).

Comment: So basically what you're saying is if I don't write code to allow 'Authorization' per se, and the user sends a token with that header, Express will automatically accept this header by default and using res.header(Access-Control-Allow-Headers ... ) doesn't really do anything , unless there is a firewall or proxy present that blocks it?

Comment: @scottwsmyth - Nothing in your question indicated you were asking about `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.  That only has to do with the browser security feature CORS for controlling cross origin requests from within the browser.  There is nothing you HAVE to do for that, it depends upon what CORS features you are trying to use or allow so the implementation depends upon your specific requirements.  If you do want to allow certain CORS requests, then you do have to configure your server appropriately so CORS will work as you desire.  By default, CORS requets will not be allowed by the browser.

Comment: @scottwsmyth - I added some info about `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`  to my answer.